# Stackdriver adapter for istio - Helm installation

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have just installed `istio` using `Helm` and enabling some adapters through the `values.yaml` file. I have enabled successfully grafana, prometheus and kiali but for some reasons stackdriver adpater is not working and it seems nothings happened for this adapter.

In the `values.yaml` file, I have just set the following:

```
    # If using stackdriver tracer outside GCP, set env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the GCP credential file.
    tracer: "stackdriver"
```

Is there something more to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

If the stack isn't running on GCP, then you need to authenticate before pushing data into Stackdriver.

[The adapter expects](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/adapters/stackdriver/#Params) the [Service Account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) of which content can be set as the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` or as a path where the Service Account JSON file is located.

From the *istio.io* blog repo, it seems that [your case needs the credentials passed as environment variable](https://github.com/istio/istio.io/blob/master/content/blog/2018/export-logs-through-stackdriver/index.md#setting-up-various-log-sinks) rather than a path.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I was missing this authentication part.